# Can I specify a destination with the ftp get command?

Tags: windows, command-line, download, ftp, batch

For example, like Windows COPY  "source" **"target"**?

or is it two steps?
Use get to download to current directory
Then do a copy to move to another location on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to specify the path along with the local file name ([see here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#get)) for Get.  If that doesn't work you may have to first change your local working directory using [the LCD command](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#lcd), and then use Get with or without just a local file name (no path).

Answer (score -1):

Often times, lcd  doesnt work (Based on experience)
I would recommend before starting the FTP session to change it

When opening CMD Prompt
we would typically be displayed with 
C:>    -this is your LCD
To change just simply type:
D:\MYfolder\placehere

Make sure the directory exist
THen, we can start FTP ^_^