# Use FTP command line to get file with absolute path

Tags: ftp

I am wondering if with an FTP command line utility, you can use the FTP `get` command to get a file with an absolute path, as opposed to having to `cd` into each successive directory to get a file.

When I type

```
ftp> get pub/sdc.tgz
```

Or even this (with one or two slashes before pub)

```
ftp> get /pub/sdc.tgz
```

It tells me it cannot find the file:

```
local: /pub/sdc.tgz remote: /pub/sdc.tgz
ftp: local: /pub/sdc.tgz: No such file or directory
```

However when I instead do

```
ftp> cd pub
ftp> get sdc.tgz
```

It works totally fine.

Is there any correct syntax in the ftp command line to get a file with an absolute path, or do I need to `cd` into `pub` first to do it?

(FYI: What I am trying to do is use a PERL script that runs daily that saves a file to an FTP server, then a later script that will 1. get the file -- which I am not opposed to using `wget` to do -- and 2. delete the file after I get it, which I need to do with FTP.  I want the file to be deleted by the second script, so that in the future if the first script has trouble saving the file to the FTP server, the second script will know that there was an error because the file is not there.  I could save it with different names too, but I do not want to pollute the FTP server with a ton of files from different days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you use FTP's Get, and don't specify a local path/file name, it tries to use the same path/name as the Remote file.

This error:

`ftp: local: /pub/sdc.tgz: No such file or directory`

Is telling you it can't find the file on the LOCAL machine. So my assumption would be that you don't have a "pub" folder on in the root of your local drive.

> Syntax: ***get*** remote-file [local-file]
>
> Parameter(s):
>
> remote-file - Specifies the remote file to copy.
>
> local-file - Specifies the name to use on the local computer. ***If not
>   specified, the file is given the remote-file name.***

So try something like:

`ftp> get pub/sdc.tgz c:\temp\sdc.tgz`

or perhaps

`ftp> get pub/sdc.tgz .\sdc.tgz`

To download it to the current folder.

See [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#get) for more info on *Get* usage.

Related SU Question: [Can I specify a destination with the ftp get command?](https://superuser.com/questions/98503/can-i-specify-a-destination-with-the-ftp-get-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ncftpget`, which uses absolute paths, if you can install it in your client machine.

Also, if you are using Perl, then you can take a look at the [FTP module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html).